# RMarkdown Position of table

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a question about table positions in rmarkdown and pdf-documents. I  created some tables and put them in my document. The problem is that some tables appear in the middle of the text and some in the appendix. But I don't know why.

Is there a setting with which I can put them all in the appendix automatically?

And where I can find more information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `library(kableExtra)` and the function `kable_styling()`. See my examples:

```
library(kableExtra)

# Left

kable(head(mtcars)) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, position = "left")

# Center

kable(head(mtcars)) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, position = "center")

# Right

kable(head(mtcars)) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F, position = "right")
```

[image]